# How to implement a property page to an eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, properties, eclipse-rcp, project

Here is the deal. I create a project in eclipse rcp programmatically. Then i add some persistant properties to it. Now i want to right click on the project in the project explorer view and then click on the properties tab. There should be my property page.
Here is what i have:

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
      <page
            adaptable="false"
            class="bg.bulsi.rcp.first.properties.SamplePropertyPage"
            id="bg.bulsi.rcp.first.properties.samplePropertyPage"
            name="Sample Page"
            nameFilter="*.*"
            objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"
            selectionFilter="single">
         <enabledWhen>
            <instanceof
                  value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
            </instanceof>
         </enabledWhen>
      </page>
   </extension>
```

why doesnt this page show up in the properties of the project?

Answer (score 6):

Try removing the "nameFilter" attribute from the page tag.  Unless you have a dot in your project name, that is probably what is preventing your properties page from showing up.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `nameFilter="*.*"` and use

`<adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
 </adapt>`

instead of `<instanceof ...></instanceof>`

(btw. options `objectCalss` and `adaptable` are deprecated)

Completely fixed:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
    <page
        class="bg.bulsi.rcp.first.properties.SamplePropertyPage"
        id="bg.bulsi.rcp.first.properties.samplePropertyPage"
        name="Sample Page"
        selectionFilter="single">
        <enabledWhen>
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
            </adapt>
        </enabledWhen>
    </page>
</extension>
```