# How to add a property page to an eclipse project (RCP / Plugin)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to add a property page to a project. In the first step i use the template wizard for the creation of a property page. I changed the targetclass value from org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile to org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject. But then i start the plugin and click on single project item the property page are not shown.

I have tested the following hints, but nothing work for me:

- [How to implement a property page to an eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409952/how-to-implement-a-property-page-to-an-eclipse-project)
- [Can I add my customized property page in projects created in RCP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355578/can-i-add-my-customized-property-page-in-projects-created-in-rcp-application)

I simplified my code to this plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
      <page
            name="TEST Sample Page"
            nameFilter="*.*"
            class="testplugin.properties.SamplePropertyPage"
            id="testplugin.properties.samplePropertyPage">
        <enabledWhen>
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
                <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature" 
                      value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature"/>
            </adapt>         
        </enabledWhen>
      </page>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Does anyone have a hint for me?

Thx.
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `nameFilter="*.*"`. This is only appropriate for trying to match particular file types, not projects.

You are also restricting the property page to only show on Java projects.

Comment: Thanks! That helps. :)